# how to toggle any text with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is very short:

If I click "show", I want to change this to "hide". Similarly, if I click "hide", I want to change this to "show"?

Such as toggleClass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Initial answer

Using the jQuery function [`toggle()` <sup>DOCs</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/):

```
$('a.toggle').click(function(){
    $('div').toggle();
});
```

### Update due to comment

#### HTML

```
<a href="#" class="cycle">Cycle</a>
<div>Text1</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var div = $('div');
var options = [div.html(), 'text2'];
var curr_opt = 1;
$('a.cycle').click(function(){
    div.text(options[curr_opt]);
    curr_opt++;
    if(!options[curr_opt]) {
        curr_opt = 0;
    }
});
```

#### Description

The above code will allow you to toggle some text, but you can add extra options to the `options` array to create a cycle if you like.

#### Running code

Here is a jsfiddle that you can run for the code: http://jsfiddle.net/c3ctT/

Comment: I'm using as below.. But does not be..
$("span[class=servers] a").toggle("hide");

Comment: Thanks for help but please read my question again. I want to use toggle with "text".

Comment: @Joseph I have updated my answer. Hopefully it is more in line with what you are after

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** fixed the code.

jQuery

```
$('#toggle').html($('#toggle').html() == 'show' ? 'hide' : 'show');
```

HTML

```
<span id="toggle">show</span>
```

Comment: The if is embedded: $('#toggle').html() == 'show' ? 'hide' : 'show'
if toggle.html is show then change it into hide, else change it into show. My code was wrong at first, but I fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Joseph, Please, Check this is what you wanted.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#showHide").html("SHOW"); 

  $("#showHide").click(function(){
   $("#content").toggle();

    if($("#content").is(":hidden"))
        $("#showHide").html("SHOW"); 
   else 
    $("#showHide").html("HIDE"); 

  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="showHide"></div>
<div id="content">
 content content..content content..content content..content content.. content content..content content..content content..content content..
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Only code required for SHOW/HIDE toggle.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#showHide").click(function(){

     if($(this).html()=="SHOW")
                $(this).html("HIDE");
     else $(this).html("SHOW");             
  });  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="showHide">SHOW</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, test second code :) You need to define the default value of show/hide. Is it what you wanted ?

Comment: i have to use "IF" in a sense? is this true?

Comment: to change the text, we need to know what the already text there is :)

Answer (score 0):

```
elem.addEventListener("click", function toggle() {
  this.classList.toggle("hidden");
});
```